Replace vertical tabs with line feeds
I am working on a google docs extension and I need to replace soft enters with line feeds. The 'soft enters' I am referring to appear the same as newlines to the naked eye, but text on both sides of them are considered part of the same paragraph, and in normal editing mode, setting one part of the chunk of text to be a Title changes all of it. When printing the content of the multiline paragraph to the console, it renders the soft enters as \r, but when I use body.replaceText(), it only finds them when I search for \v. If I do body.replaceText("\\v", '[enter]');, that works as expected, replacing the soft enters, but when I try to replace them with line feeds: body.replaceText("\\v", '\n');, the code executes with no errors but has no effect, leaving the soft enters in the document. I tried body.replaceText("\\v", '\\n');, but this puts literal '\n'. I have a feeling this is because any attempt to put a newline into the middle of a paragraph gets interpreted as a soft enter, but I don't know how to fix this. How do I make it actually start a new paragraph instead of having a soft enter?

I think that the vertical tabulation \v can be used as \u000b as the Unicode. How about using this? So, in your situation, if you can use Google Docs API, how about the following sample script?
Sample script:
Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Document.
Before you use this script, please enable Google Docs API at Advanced Google services.
function myFunction() {
  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  const requests = [{ replaceAllText: { replaceText: "\n", containsText: { text: "\u000b" } } }];
  Docs.Documents.batchUpdate({ requests }, doc.getId());
}

Note:

The soft breaks can be searched with findText("\\v"). But, when replaceText("\\v", '\n') is run, it seems that \n is used as the soft breaks. I'm not sure whether this is the current specification or a bug. From this situation, I thought that Google Docs API might be able to be used. But, it seems that Google Docs API cannot search the soft breaks with \v. So, I thought that \u000b might be able to be used.

Testing:
When this script is run with a sample Document, the following result is obtained.

References:

Method: documents.batchUpdate
ReplaceAllTextRequest

